# Some function gives wrong results instead of None

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to print only two fields from two functions. The both functions take the same url but produce different results. The first function `get_names()` prints the name of different users. The second function `get_badges()` produces the number of badges connected to concerning users. ***As the number of badges is not always present in every users, I used `zip_longest()` so that if any user doesn't have any badges, the function will print `None`***. However, the problem is `get_badges()` function gives me wrong results when it encounters any user not having any badges.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_names(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".user-details > a"):
        yield item.text

def get_badges(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".badgecount"):
        yield item.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for elem in zip_longest(get_names(url),get_badges(url)):
        print(elem)
```

***How can I let the two functions produce accurate results?***

- NOTE: I'm using two API's which produce different results (correlated) against different ID's. I just tried to mimick the same logic above what I'm doing with those API's.

Comment: We can't really debug this if you don't show the actual URLs you are using

Comment: It is probably the case that when a user has no badges, the HTML will have no element with class `badgecount` and the user will be skipped in the function `get_badges` but not in `get_names`. This would cause misalignment of the results. A better solution would be to fetch the HTML once, then extract the users and pass each user to a function that extracts both attributes.

Comment: What does it anything to do with the actual urls @DeepSpace? The above script represents what I'm trying to achieve. Btw, the count of badges are not always right when any user dont have one.

Comment: @MITHU It has everything to do with the actual URLs. How can we debug if we don't know what actual input/output you are working with?

Comment: create one function which gets parent for both elements and inside parent it search `name` and `badget` to create pair. This way you have always correct name and badget or None in correct pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above, you need something that "connects" results from `get_names()` and `get_badges()`. In your code, there's nothing like it - so the results will be mismatched in zip.

In this code I use CSS selector `.user-details` as common element between the two functions. In your code you can have common element in the form of user name, or user id, etc. and return a dictionary/tuple from each function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'

def get_names(soup):
    for item in soup.select(".user-details > a"):
        yield item.text

def get_badges(soup):
    for item in soup.select(".user-details"):
        gold = item.select_one('.badge1 + .badgecount')
        silver = item.select_one('.badge2 + .badgecount')
        bronze = item.select_one('.badge3 + .badgecount')

        yield [int(gold.text) if gold else 0,
               int(silver.text) if silver else 0,
               int(bronze.text) if bronze else 0]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    print('{: <30}{: >5}{: >5}{: >5}'.format('Name', 'G', 'S', 'B'))
    print('-' * 45)
    for name, badges in zip(get_names(soup), get_badges(soup)):
        print('{: <30}{}'.format(name, ''.join('{: >5}'.format(b) for b in badges)))
```

Prints:

```
Name                              G    S    B
---------------------------------------------
Arkadi w                          0    0    7
MITHU                             0    4   18
Mohamed Suhail Irfan Khazi        0    0    2
Kevin Walsh                       0    0    2
lowpeasant                        0    0    0
vivekh99                          0    0    2
Nico Gandolfo                     0    0    1
Sam Edeus                         0    0    2
Tab Key                           0    0    7
Ion Aag                           0    0    5

... and so on.
```

Comment: @MITHU Your approach in the code is perfectly fine. But note, you too select `.user-details` in both functions. And this `.user-details` is what keeps the two functions "in sync".

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to correlate those two lists!

You have no way of finding the correspondence between the user's name and the number of badge, look, if you do:

```
print(list(get_names(url)))
print(list(get_badges(url)))
```

You'll get:

```
['Arkadi w', 'MITHU', 'Mohamed Suhail Irfan Khazi', 'Kevin Walsh', 'lowpeasant', 'vivekh99', 'Nico Gandolfo', ... ]
['7', '4', '18', '2', '2', '2', '1', ...]
```

But if you zip those lists, th 2 badges of 'vivekh99' will be attributed to 'lowpeasant', who has no badges!

The only way I can imagine is to change your `get_badges` method to return a tuple of the form (name, badges), or a dictionary. Something like that:

```
def get_badges(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".user-details"):
        yield (item.find('a').text, [s.text for s in item.find_all('span', { "class" : "badgecount" })])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently.

First, you request the same URL twice. So that logic would need to be removed from both functions and placed elsewhere to prevent this from happening. Instead of trying to zip both results together I would iterate over user details and parse those in different functions, removing zip altogether as this is causing your inconsistencies.

basically in pseudocode

```
def _retrieve_user(question):
    return "userthing"

def _retrieve_badgecount(question):
    # Handle no badge-count
    return 1 or 0

def parse_question(question):
    # get user info
    # get badecount     
    return _retrieve_user(question=question), 
        _retrieve_badgecount(question=question)

def main(url):
    # get url
    # make soup

    # iterate over questions using beautifullsoup siblings
    return [parse_question(q) for q in ("question_1", "question_2")]
```

This should have the single responsibility concern covered and has no repetition.

Good luck!